# How can the MVC View determine which ActionResult passed the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there anyway in a MVC strongly typed View to find out which `ActionResult` in the controller passed the Model? I do not want to add extra fields in the Model at this stage or add anything in my querystring? Is it even possible?
Sorry this may be a noob question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That sort of violates the principles of the [MVC Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller). You now want the view to be aware of the controller.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have a set of 4 booleans like µC register which I want to manipulate in my view rather than doing it in model I find it easier to do this in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind mumbling about validation of the principles of the MVC Architecture ;)

Place this code in your view:

```
string action = @ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks that is quite helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In the view you can acess the Context, then you can retrieve the action/controller from the current request like this:

```
@{
    string controller = RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    string action = RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
}
```

Then you can use it at the view to make some conditional

```
@if(action.Equals("some name"))
{
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Action should tell the View.  Instead of adding extra fields to your model you could wrap it in a ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public MyModel InnerModel {get; set; }
    public string ActionName {get; set; }
}
```

Or use ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.ActionName = "MyActionName";
```